# setState inside componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle Recompose HOC

Tags: javascript, recompose

I'd like to change local state everytime I received a new upcoming props. For this purposes I use a `lifecycle` HOC from `Recompose` library. But it's not as simple as I thought. I either set the value forever or the stack overflow occurs when using the callback.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withState, withProps, lifecycle, compose } from 'recompose';
import { selectors, testDelete, testSubscribe } from 'ducks/entities/tests';
import { Tests } from 'components/tests/all-tests';

export default compose(
  connect(selectors.tests, {
    onTestDelete: testDelete,
    onTestSubscribe: testSubscribe,
  }),
  withState('isDeleteModalOpen', 'setDeleteModalShow', false),
  withState('idToDelete', 'setIdToDelete', 0),
  withProps(
    ({
      tests,
      idToDelete,
      setIdToDelete,
      setDeleteModalShow,
      onTestDelete,
      onTestSubscribe,
    }) => ({
      tests: tests.map((t) =>
        t.merge({
          onDeleteModalShow: () => {
            setDeleteModalShow(true);
            setIdToDelete(t.get('id'));
          },
          onSubscribe: () => onTestSubscribe(t.get('id')),
        }),
      ),
      onDeleteModalHide: () => setDeleteModalShow(false),
      onDelete: () => onTestDelete(idToDelete),
    }),
  ),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillReceiveProps({ setDeleteModalShow }) {
      setDeleteModalShow(false); // Not workding "Maximum update depth exceeded"

      this.setState({
        isDeleteModalOpen: false,
      }); // now working
    },
  }),
)(Tests);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat old question, but the answer is fairly simple.

Don't change the state if the value you're setting is already the value that you want it to be. In your code, you could change the `lifecycle` enhancer to check if the `isDeleteModalOpen` is already false, like so:

```
lifecycle({
  componentWillReceiveProps({ setDeleteModalShow, isDeleteModalOpen }) {
    if (isDeleteModalOpen) setDeleteModalShow(false);
  },
}),
```

This way your `componentWillReceiveProps` function will hit twice and it will do nothing on the second time.

Be aware that any prop change on this component will set the `isDeleteModalOpen` value to false.